# polynomial approximation of hypergeometric function 2F1

Tags: polynomials, binomial-coefficients, hypergeometric-functions, physics, gamma-function

I have the following function $T(k_1,k_2)$ resulting from multiphoton transition matrix elements calculations:

$T(k_1,k_2)=\gamma^{-k_2}\sum_{j=0}^{k_1}(j+2)_{l+1}\binom{k_1}{j}(k_1+1)_3(\gamma-1)^{j}{}_2F_1\left(-k_2,j+l+5,2+2l;1+\gamma\right)$

where $k_1,k_2,l,j$ are non-negative integers and $\gamma$ could in general be complex.

The function $T$ should be a polynomial in $k_1$ and $k_2$ such that

$T=\sum_{m,n}Q_{m,n}k_1^mk_2^n$.

I am trying to find some closed-form representation for the coefficients $Q_{m,n}$.
In my calculations, I had some other similar functions where I found the coefficients exactly, but I could not figure out a way for this one.
At this point, even an approximation would be helpful.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Provided $-k_2$ is indeed a non-negative integer, the hypergeometric function degenerates to a [Jacobi polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_polynomials#Via_the_hypergeometric_function). Wikipedia also gives explicitly the coefficients of Jacobi polynomials. Is that sufficient for your purposes?

Comment: The explicit coefficients given are of a polynomial at z.
I am looking for a polynomial at n, in terms of the Jacobi polynomial.

Comment: (* of course, $-k_2$ must be a _non-positive_ integer) From the explicit formulas for Jacobi polynomials, it is not clear that the dependence on $k_2$ of your expression will actually be polynomial. Do you have any reason to expect such a special property?

Comment: I have no proof that this function is a finite polynomial, 
but it should be able to be represented as an infinite polynomial.
After that, it is only a matter of making an approximation by truncating the sum at some point.